# Is there a way to refer to child classes with the parent classes namespace/classspace?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, namespaces, c++20

Suppose I have the following `Mouse Event` class with a `Button` event and extending `Button Press` and `Button Release` events:

```
namespace Event {
    namespace Mouse {
        class Button : public Event {
          public:
            inline Input::Code::Mouse get_mouse_button() const {
                return m_Button;
            }
    
            EVENT_CLASS_CATEGORY(Event_Category_Input | Event_Category_Mouse)
          protected:
            Button(Input::Code::Mouse button)
                : m_Button(button) {}
            Input::Code::Mouse m_Button;
        };
    
        class Press : public Button {
          public:
            Press(Input::Code::Mouse button) : Button(button) {}
    
            std::string to_string() const override {
                return fmt::format("Mouse Button Press: {0}", m_Button);
            }
    
            EVENT_CLASS_TYPE(Mouse_Button_Press)
        };
    
        class Release : public Button {
          public:
            Release(Input::Code::Mouse button)
                : Button(button) {}
    
            std::string to_string() const override {
                return fmt::format("Mouse Button Release: ", m_Button);
            }
    
            EVENT_CLASS_TYPE(Mouse_Button_Release)
        };
    }
}
```

I would like to refer to these with `Event::Mouse::Button::Press` and `Event::Mouse::Button::Release` instead of `Event::Mouse::Press` and `Event::Mouse::Release`. I cannot directly add the `namespace Button` to force this behavior because it would conflict with the `Button` class which is already defined. Is there a way to accomplish this? I understand I could name it `Button_Press` and `Button_Release` respectively, but I'd prefer not to for stylistic reasons. Thanks in advance! If it's not possible, I'll just suck it up and use the underscores.

Comment: Can you edit the `Button` class?

Comment: Sure, in what way do you suggest?

Comment: Which answer do I accept if I got two identical answers at the same time basically?

Comment: Time shouldn't matter.  Just do your best attempt to accept whichever answer you judge to be best.  There are no hard feelings here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Forward declare these types in your `Button` class.

That gives the types the scope you want.

```
class Button : public Event {
  public:

    class Press;
    class Release;        

};
```

Then, outside the class you may define them.

You must define them outside the class, so the parent class `Button` is completely defined.

```
class Button::Press : public Button {
public:

};

class Button::Release : public Button {
public:

};
```

Comment: Awesome! This is alot more intuitive than I thought, oops! Does this have any preformance implications?

Comment: It affects a type's _scope_, which has no performance implications

Answer (score 3):

Since you want `Press` and `Release` to be part of `Event::Mouse::Button` in name, I would make them part of `Event::Mouse::Button` in definition. The only trick here is that the definitions of `Press` and `Release` cannot be inside the definition of `Button` (but their declarations must still be there).

```cpp
namespace Event {
    namespace Mouse {
        class Button : public Event {
            class Press;    // <-- declare here
            class Release;
        };
        // End of class Button
    
        // Begin definition of Button::Press
        class Button::Press : public Button {
        };
    
        // Begin definition of Button::Release
        class Button::Release : public Button {
        };
    }
}
```

(Please note how I removed unnecessary and distracting clutter from your example. This also makes the example more complete, lacking only a definition of the `Event` class that `Button` extends.)